# Is it possible to expand SearchView without showing the keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, searchview

I have SearchView in action bar. It expands when user clicks it and then keyboard appears. This is expected behavior. However, in my app there's one case when I expand SearchView programmatically.

```
MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem);
```

I don't want to show keyboard in this case. I expand SearchView programmatically just to show user what was the last search query.

So is it possible to open search view without showing the keyboard?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @gersonmendes, I didn't find a solution. But if I had to use SearchView again I would google about that elaborate view used in Play Store. It is much better than the usual SearchView. 
http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/larger_wm_brw/public/article_images/2015/03/google-play-update.JPG?itok=sIj0Zj7E

Answer (score 4):

I resolve my problem using this:

```
@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search));
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearch)){
            searchView.setQuery(mSearch, false);
            searchView.setIconified(false);
            searchView.clearFocus();
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this code resolve your problem.

Comment: CLEAR ANSWER: Combination of `searchView.setIconified(false);` and `searchView.clearFocus();`

Answer (score 1):

I used below code to expand searchview without opening keyboard:

```
searchView.setFocusable(false);
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.clearFocus();
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my app I wanted to have a SearchView meeting these requirements:

1. SearchView is expanded by default and cannot be collapsed by the user
2. The keyboard doesn't appear automatically but only when user clicks the SearchView

I managed to get the expected result with this.

**activity_search.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:queryHint="Search..." />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SearchActivity.kt**

```
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        // Perform search either here or in onQueryTextSubmit()
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        // Clear focus here to avoid situation where in order to exit the activity you have to click Back twice
        // This happens if you click "Search" button on your keyboard and then want to exit the activity.
        // First Back click clears SearchView focus while the second click exits the activity.
        // You don't want to click twice, do you?
        search_view.clearFocus()
        return false
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> { onBackPressed(); true }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: With kotlin you can accomplish this programmatically with `searchView.isIconifiedByDefault = false`, probably in java there is a `setIsIconifiedByDefault` function. I don't need clearFocus at all

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this issus. Please override the method as below code --

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

    searchView = ((SearchView) menuItem.getActionView());

    searchView.setFocusable(true);
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    menuItem.setVisible(true);

}
```